# How to reset Django admin password?

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, passwords, django-admin

I am using Django (version 1.3) and have forgotten both admin username and password. How to reset both?

And is it possible to make a normal user into admin, and then remove admin status?

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in one post.

Answer (score 1161, accepted):

```
python manage.py changepassword <user_name>
```

[see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords)

Comment: just realised that you said you forgot the username... 'admin' being the username in my answer wont be much help then!

Comment: @user794916 That's rather strange choice if you don't remember the username. :-)

Comment: You can change the user name from "admin" to another proper user nam. :D

Comment: You can open the sqlite database with a third party app and check the usernames (not the passwords)

Comment: django's the best. everything is just so easy

Comment: If you've forgotten the username, you can do `manage.py createsuperuser` to create a 2nd superuser, and then view the list of Users to find the original one. Then log in as the original one and delete the new superuser.

Comment: If you just type command as shown in this answer without specifying a username, the command will let you change the password for the current system user and display it while doing so.

Answer (score 221):

1. `python manage.py createsuperuser` will create another superuser, you will be able to log into admin and rememder your username.
2. Yes, why not.

To give a normal user privileges, open a shell with `python manage.py shell` and try:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(username='normaluser')
user.is_superuser = True
user.save()
```

Comment: If its possible , how to do it ?

Comment: With this approach seems that the user can't access django admin

Comment: @LucaFabbri you would also need to set `user.is_staff = True`

Answer (score 175):

You may try through console:

```
python manage.py shell
```

then use following script in shell

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
```

will list you all super users on the system. if you recognize yur username from the list:

```
usr = User.objects.get(username='your username')
usr.set_password('raw password')
usr.save()
```

and you set a new password (:

Comment: `User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)`

Comment: `pip install django-extensions`, add it to `installed apps` and run `./manage.py shell_plus`. The `User` class will be available and you can `password-change`.

Comment: This method allows user to set any password, without any validation. You can thus set a very simple password (just for test purposes), which the accepted answer method does not allow.

Answer (score 27):

**In addition** to @JamesO answer that states using

```
python manage.py changepassword [username]
```

#### if you don't remember your username :

1- while in your project's main directory access the database (I'm using sqlite3):

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite3
```

2- list the content of the `auth_user` table

```
SELECT * FROM auth_user ;
```

3- look for the user that has `is_superuser = 1` , in my case it's admin
[screenshot of the command output (I don't have enough rep points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a61nD.png)

Answer (score 26):

You can create a new superuser with [`createsuperuser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#django-admin-createsuperuser) command.

Answer (score 18):

This is very good question.

python manage.py changepassword user_name

Example :-

```
python manage.py changepassword mickey
```

Answer (score 15):

One of the best ways to retrieve the username and password is to view and update them. The User Model provides a perfect way to do so.

## In this case, I'm using Django 1.9

1. Navigate to your root directory i,e. where you "manage.py" file is located using your console or other application such as Git.
2. Retrieve the Python shell using the command  "python manage.py shell".
3. Import the User Model by typing the following command
   "from django.contrib.auth.models import User"
4. Get all the users by typing the following command
   "users = User.objects.all()"
5. Print a list of the users
   For Python 2 users use the command "print users"
   For Python 3 users use the command "print(users)"
   The first user is usually the admin.
6. Select the user you wish to change their password e.g.

   `"user = users[0]"`
7. Set the password

   `user.set_password('name_of_the_new_password_for_user_selected')`
8. Save the new password

   `"user.save()"`

Start the server and log in using the username and the updated password.

Comment: The advantage of this method over `manage.py changepassword` is that you're not restricted to what passwords you can or can't use - no more too similar to username crap. (This is in my dev environment. I'm not advocating weaker passwords. You should always use strong passwords in prod.)

Answer (score 13):

**new setup** should **first run** `python manage.py createsuperuser` to create user. It seems like there is no default username password to login into admin.

Answer (score 12):

```
python manage.py changepassword username
```

Answer (score 12):

Two ways to do this:

The `changepassword` **management command**:

```
(env) $ python manage.py changepassword <username>
```

Or (which expands upon a few answers, but works for any extended User model) using the **django-admin shell** as follows:

```
(env) $ python manage.py shell
```

This should bring up the shell command prompt as follows:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar 27 2019, 08:44:46) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
```

Then you would want the following:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> User = get_user_model()
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='admin@hug.com')
>>> user.set_password('new password')
>>> user.save()
>>> exit()
```

**N.B.** Why have I answered this question with this answer?

Because, as mentioned, `User = get_user_model()` will work for your own custom `User` models. Using `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` then `User.objects.get(username='username')` may throw the following error:

```
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'
```

Comment: This answer is a good way to set a common/short password for an existing user.

Answer (score 7):

You may try this:

1.Change Superuser password without console

```
python manage.py changepassword <username>
```

2.Change Superuser password through console

[image]
[image]

Comment: Using screenshots instead of written code is very bad practice. Poeple can not Copy-Paste your code to test and it is not available for in-site-search

Answer (score 5):

You may also have answered a setup question wrong and have zero staff members.  In which case head to postgres:

```
obvioustest=# \c [yourdatabasename]
obvioustest=# \x
obvioustest=# select * from auth_user;
-[ RECORD 1 ]+-------------
id           | 1
is_superuser | f
is_staff     | f
...
```

To fix, edit directly:

```
update auth_user set is_staff='true' where id=1;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you forgot create admin user first build one with `createsuperuser` command on `manage.py` then change the password.

Answer (score 5):

if you forget your admin then you need to create new user by using

```
python manage.py createsuperuser <username>
```

and for password there is CLI  command `changepassword`  for django to change user password

```
python manage.py changepassword <username>
```

OR

```
django-admin changepassword <username>
```

OR Run this code in Django env

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username='john')
u.set_password('new password')
u.save()
```

Answer (score 5):

### If you're using custom user model

```
(venv)your_prj $ ./manage.py shell
>>> from customusers.models import CustomUser
>>> CustomUser.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
>>> user = CustomUser.objects.get(email="somesuper@sys.com")
>>> user.set_password('@NewPwd')
>>> user.save()
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you do not know the usernames as created here. You can get the users as described by @FallenAngel above.

```
python manage.py shell 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
usrs = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
#identify the user
your_user = usrs.filter(username="yourusername")[0]
#youruser = usrs.get(username="yourusername")
#then set the password
```

However in the event that you created your independent user model. A simple case is when you want to use email as a username instead of the default user name. In which case your user model lives somewhere such as your_accounts_app.models then the above solution wont work.
In this case you can instead use the get_user_model method

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 
super_users = get_user_model().objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
#proceed to get identify your user
# and set their user password
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that is worth noting is to set your user's status `is_staff` as active. At least, that's what makes it works for me. For more detail, I created another `superuser` as people explained above. Then I go to the database table `auth_user` and search for that username to make sure its `is_staff` flag is set to `1`. That finally allowed me to log into `admin` site.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new superuser with the command "python manage.py createsuperuser".
Login as the new super user. Click on the 'users' link. Then click on the user you want to delete. click on delete user at the end of the form page.

Note - The above process will make changes to the activity logs done by that particular user.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to just go to your terminal and type

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

and insert another password and user name again 
but u will lost some of your profile that u have created before in most cases.

Comment: Please don't follow this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just type this command in your command line:

```
python manage.py changepassword yourusername
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> python manage.py dumpdata

then look at the end you will find the user name

Comment: The dump may contain user name but password is hashed with a one-way hash function, which should not be (and is not) useful for restoring the password. Also, it is unnecessary to dump the database for browsing when the user has access to the running database and can connect to it with a proper client.

Answer (score 0):

I think,The better way
At the command line

> python manage.py createsuperuser

Answer (score 0):

If a `reset_password` link is needed in the `/admin/ website` this is the way to go:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-a-password-reset-feature

Answer (score -4):

Another way to get the user name (and most of the information) is to access the database directly and read the info from the tables.