# How to Reset The Admin Password in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to reset django admin password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358030/how-to-reset-django-admin-password)

I have worked for Django project in local server. The current updates need to fix on web server . But couldnt match the admin credentials . So how can reset  the admin password...

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you know the name of a superuser: [`django-admin.py changepassword`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-changepassword)

Answer (score 7):

Run this in the project on the server to create a new super user

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```