# Locked out of Mezzanine Admin

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I finally got mezzanine running but deleted my user account because there was a mispelling in the email address. Didn't realize it would kick me out of the system after deletion. So now there are no user accounts set up in Mezzanine and I have no way to get back into admin. Is there a workaround for this? I am guessing the credentials are stored in the DB. Maybe I can add a record for a new user that way?

Comment: Mezzanine is just an overlay of Django? If so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358030/how-to-reset-django-admin-password

Comment: Thanks. I nuked the install and started over but I'll keep this in mind for next time.